# verilog mux not working

Tags: verilog, multiplexing

I wanted to build a small code for 2*1 mux where the inputs come from different modules (to make it more practical), but I'm always getting output as High Impedence ('Z'). Any suggestions?

```
module  mux_using_assign(
  din_0      , // Mux first input
  din_1      , // Mux Second input
  sel        , // Select input
  mux_out      // Mux output
  );
  input din_0, din_1, sel ;
  output mux_out;
  wire  mux_out;
  assign mux_out = (sel) ? din_1 : din_0;

  endmodule //End Of Module mux


  module ip1();
  wire a;
  mux_using_assign dut1(.din_0(a));
  assign a = 1;
  endmodule


  module ip2();
  wire b;
  mux_using_assign dut1(.din_1(b));
  assign b = 0;
  endmodule



  module test();
  wire sel        ; // Select input
  wire mux_out;
  ip1 aa();    // tried commenting this and following line also
  ip2 bb();
  mux_using_assign dut1(.sel(sel),.mux_out(mux_out));
  assign sel=1;
  endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `dut1` instance in each module is a separate instance from the other modules. In other words, each of `ip1`, `ip2`, and `test` have their own `dut1` muxer. You'll need to use input/output wires and link them all to a single `mux_using_assign` declaration.

Comment: jut want to confirm, providing same name to all instances of mux doesn't imply they are the same physical block?

Comment: so is there a way to do so using the syntax only, and not going for all the detailed wiring solution (looking for an easier way out), because this is just an experimental code for a bigger project. I have to implement an arbiter which takes input from different blocks and accesses memory output based on the selected input block.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Besides, the wiring solution isn't all that "detailed" - in fact, it's arguably better than what you're trying to do, as it separates interface from implementation.